# Value of quotient of two finite series involving reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a middle school examination question for which  I do not seek a solution: simply a hint on how to approach the problem.

The question was originally worded as in the attached image.[image: Original question.]

I have rephrased it so, hoping to see a pattern emerge.

Without the use of a calculator, evaluate $S_1/S_2$ where

$S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{2006} (-1)^{i+1}\thinspace\frac{1}{i} $

and

$S_2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{1003}\thinspace\frac{1}{i+1003}$

P.S. Please do not post a solution only a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: Was it a Middle School for hyper gifted kids?

Comment: @Raffaele: I do not know. A friend from Singapore sent it to me online. I live elsewhere. He said "secondary school" which might cover up to year 10 AFAIK.